# Why can't I read data from /dev/snd/midi*?

Tags: linux, usb, midi, alsa

Why does this USB MIDI device (Korg Nanokontrol) produce data that can be read from /dev/snd/midiC2D0 when a knob is turned

[image]

But this one doesn't? (Egosys MIDIMATE II)

[image]

The arrow indicates a led which is flashing as midi data comes in. The type of the MIDI messages in this case are "midi clock" that I'm trying to use to tell a tempo of a song which is being played elsewhere to this computer.

It can also be confirmed with Wireshark USB sniffing that the correct kind of data is being transmitted through USB to the computer (at least I think it's correct).

[image]

I'm also sure that the device midiC1D0 is the right device because it appears and disappears when I plug and unplug the device.

So why is the data never reaching /dev/snd/midiC1D0 even though there is data coming in?

I've also tried using alsa functions directly [as shown in this code example](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2rawmidi_8c-example.html) but the result is the same: the read function reads nothing.

Comment: `1f f8` is a valid USB MIDI packet for a MIDI Clock message on the second port. (Does `amidi -l` show two input ports?) It's possible that `cat` will not show data that cannot be interpreted as UTF-8 characters; use [amidi](http://linux.die.net/man/1/amidi) or [aseqdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/aseqdump) to show incoming MIDI messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CL's comment was correct. Amidi shows the right data. So now I just gotta code the same thing that amidi does. Thanks!

```
apaksi@extruder:/dev/snd$ amidi -l
Dir Device    Name
IO  hw:0,0,0  nanoKONTROL MIDI 1
IO  hw:1,0,0  MIDIMATE II MIDI 1
IO  hw:1,0,1  MIDIMATE II MIDI 2
apaksi@extruder:/dev/snd$ amidi -d -p hw:1,0,1 

F8
F8
F8
F8
F8
F8
F8
F8
```